# Looking for a regex to get the data stored within the angle <> brackets

Tags: php, html

Ok I tried to google it but couldn't find a solution so I am asking here. I am trying to save the HTML tags into a variable in php. I am trying to use preg_match but cannot find the right pattern(regex). I did find one regex `'\s*(.*?)\s*>\s*'`. This works ok on the functions-online site where I try it and gives me the whole tag i.e.`i=<body>` but when I try to run it in my programme I get

```
preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash
```

It would be helpful if anyone could sort out this issue and even better if anyone could give the regex to get the data within the angle brackets(HTML tags)

Please also let me know if there is another method to store the html tags in php i.e.

```
<body>
```

then `$var=body`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) <-- Read the 1st answer if you are considering "parsing" HTML with regexes
2. You need to add so called delimiters: `'/\s*(.*?)\s*>\s*/'`

Comment: Any other way you can think of to get the tag without the brackets?

Comment: If you are using PHP5 you can take a look at http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Comment: Hey I did look at it but coudln't understand much lol will try it again Thanxx again killer X

Comment: I basically just need the tag name not the text between the tags

Comment: what happens if you have this: `<script>var a = '<a href="haha.html">FOO</a>';</script>`?  This is just a very simple example but you can see how easy it is to get (at the very least) wrong results when using regex.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Thanx to the link provided by killerx I did find a regex which could be use but it is not the best method but should work for my task

```
'\'<([a-z]+)[^>]*(?<!/)>\''
```

This should work. It will get the full tag in an array and the tag description in the other.
Thanx a ton for helping me out